# Whats the cons of having different versions of AKS cluster and Node Pool Kubernetes version?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am having a node pool which is 1.13.12 and AKS version 1.15.5.

Is it fine to have different versions? And is there any cons?

I got this screen during the node upgrade. I couldn't update the node version in my current region

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's fine to have different versions of the AKS cluster and node pool. What affection is that you cannot use the features of the new version in the node pool as I know.

And then for the upgrade, there is a table for AKS and it shows that which versions can upgrade for the current version for the different regions. It looks like this:

[image]

And you can use the CLI command `az aks get-versions -l region` to get the table above.

So you need to meet the rules when you upgrade the version. For example, if you want to upgrade into version 15.5 and you are 1.13.12, then you need to upgrade to 1.14.8 first, and upgrade to 1.15.5 after finishing the first upgrading.